# A way to fingerprint / determine websites that use Pug as a template engine?

Tags: pug

I need a way to fingerprint websites / web apps that uses pug as a template engine, for example: a specific string in the response of those web apps , specific regex or script file link when you could determine that if one of those 3 exist in the response of that web application then it is mostly uses pug as a template engine.

Comment: There's https://builtwith.com/ but that's likely going to only tell you client-side tools, not server side rendering tools

Comment: I believe it is going to tell me that the site is using Node JS and not pug, otherwise, if it detect pug then i'm more interested in the way that the plugin used to detect it..

Comment: HTML template engines dont inject any markers or tags to say which is being used. At least, not intentionally, as that could be used my malicious actors to inject bad behavior (ref. Struts + Equifax hack)